# Unable to test vue component with v-dialog

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vue-component, vuetify.js, vitest

I have been killing myself trying to figure out how to test a Vue component with a v-dialog, something which worked perfectly fine in Vue2. Currently I am using Vue3, Vitest, Vuetify3.

here is a very simple **component** which demonstrates a problem

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn @click.stop="dialog=true" class="open-dialog-btn">click me please</v-btn>
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="290" >
      <div class="dialog-content">
        <v-card>welcome to dialog</v-card>
      </div>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {ref} from "vue";

const dialog = ref(false);
</script>
```

and here is a **unit test** for it:

```
import '../setup';
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";
import HelloDialog from "@/components/HelloDialog.vue";

describe('HelloDialog', () => {
  let wrapper;
  let vuetify;

  beforeEach(() => {
    vuetify = createVuetify();
  });

  describe('dialog tests', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = mount(HelloDialog, {
        global: {
          plugins: [vuetify],
        },
      });
    });

    test('test dialog', async () => {
      expect(wrapper.find('.dialog-content').exists()).toBeFalsy();
      await wrapper.find('.open-dialog-btn').trigger('click');
      console.log(wrapper.html());
      expect(wrapper.find('.dialog-content').exists()).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
});
```

the last line in unit test is not working - dialog content is not displayed. Here is an output from wrapper.html() after button is clicked:

```
<div><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--elevated v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--size-default v-btn--variant-elevated open-dialog-btn"><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span>
    <!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator="">click me please</span>
    <!---->
    <!---->
  </button>
  <!---->
  <!--teleport start-->
  <!--teleport end-->
</div>

AssertionError: expected false to be truthy
    at ....../HelloDialog.spec.js:27:56
```

here is test section from **vite.config.js**:

```
  test: {
    // https://vitest.dev/config/
    globals:true,
    environment: 'happy-dom',
    setupFiles: "vuetify.config.js",
    deps: {
      inline: ["vuetify"],
    },
  },
```

and here is **vuetify.config.js**:

```
global.CSS = { supports: () => false };
```

here some versions from **package.json**:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "7.1.96",
    "@pinia/testing": "^0.0.14",
    "axios": "^1.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "happy-dom": "^8.1.1",
    "jsdom": "^20.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "pinia": "^2.0.27",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "vue": "^3.2.45",
    "vuetify": "3.0.6",
    "webfontloader": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.2.6",
    "vite": "^4.0.3",
    "vite-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
    "vitest": "^0.26.2"
  }
```

I have tried everything at this point, and I think the problem has something to do with v-dialog using teleport component. After struggling for several days trying to figure out I settled on using a stub to not use a real dialog when testing but I really don't like this approach.

any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Any success here?

Comment: Yes, there are 2 ways to proceed. One option is listed below as an answer. The other option is to create a MockDialog which can be used instead of the dialog component during testing. Once you create a MockDialog component you can replace it using stubs options (VDialog: MockDialog) when mounting a control.  I got to say I like using MockDialog more because then I can use all the helper utils I built around vitest/jest

Comment: @Andrey can you please share how you were able to get around this? I am having the same issue now and do not fully understand the MockComponent comment. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue and found the content of `v-dialog` was rendered in `document.body` when I called `mount()`.
You can test the dialog content like below.

```js
// expect(wrapper.find('.dialog-content').exists()).toBeTruthy();
expect(document.querySelector('.dialog-content')).not.toBeNull();
```

I recommend to call `unmount()` after each test.

```js
afterEach(() => {
  wrapper.unmount()
});
```

Hope this helps although I doubt it's a good approach because I don't want to care whether the component is using teleport or not.

Comment: thanks. definitely will try it when I have a min

Comment: Your solution definitely works! Thank you. However this takes me outside of vitest framework and it's just a bit harder to do things as I no longer work with a wrapper which provides all kids of utilities but instead of dom elements. I will continue exploring this option.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the internals of vuetify works for the `v-dialog` component, but it seems like they use the `<Teleport>` component, try adding the element where the contents of the teleport will land, the `id` has to match though for whatever name they are using, check their docs probably they have some props for this

```js
beforeEach(() => {
 const el = document.createElement('div');
 el.id = 'my-teleport';
 document.body.appendChild(el);
});
```

Comment: Very nice and clean implementation. I'll try your method as well - I actually crated a stub component

Answer (score 0):

Using Andrey's comment to create a MockDialog stub, I was able to solve my problem. Here's a solution that I used:

test-utils.ts

```js
export function stub(
  tag: string,
  opts ? : {
    [key: string]: any
  },
  template ? : string,
): ComponentPublicInstance < any > {
  const contents = template || `Stubbed ${tag}`;
  return {
    name: pascalCase(tag),
    template: `<div class="${tag}-stub">${contents}</div>`,
    ...(opts || {}),
  };
}

export const sharedStubs = {
  vDialog: stub(
    'v-dialog', {
      props: ['modelValue'],
    },
    '<slot />',
  ),
}
```

Then, in my *.spec.ts using the `v-dialog` component:

```js
mount(
  ComponentWithModal, {
    global: {
      plugins: [
        vuetify,
      ],
      stubs: {
        VDialog: sharedStubs.vDialog,
      },
    }
    as GlobalMountOptions,
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works for me in Vue 2 (jest).

1. Use this in the test stubs:

```
stubs: {
      VDialog: {
        name: 'VDialog',
        template: '<div class="v-dialog-stub"><slot /></div>',
        props: ['modelValue'],
      },
}
```

2. Trigger the dialog in the test, wait for nextTick:

```
it('Modal dialog test', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, options);  // options = test options, including (1.)

    const dialogTrigger = wrapper.find('.my-dialog-trigger');
    dialogTrigger.trigger('click');

    await Vue.nextTick();
    const dialog = wrapper.find('.v-dialog-stub');
    expect(dialog.exists()).toBe(true);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to set the `attach` props to true. So when you mount the component during test, the dialog content will be rendered in the wrapper.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-dialog/#props-attach