# Snapshot component testing with Vitest and Vuetify: failed to resolve component

Tags: vuejs3, vitest, vuetifyjs3

I'm trying to perform snapshot tests with Vitest on a Vue 3 component with Vuetify 3.
Here's my test:

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify';
import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest';
import ConfirmationModal from '@/components/ConfirmationModal.vue';

const vuetify = createVuetify();

global.ResizeObserver = require('resize-observer-polyfill');

describe(`Composant ConfirmationModal`, () => {
  it(`Match snapshot`, async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      {
        template: '<v-layout><confirmation-modal></confirmation-modal></v-layout>'
      },
      {
        props: {
          value: true,
          title: 'test',
          width: 100
        },
        global: { components: { ConfirmationModal }, plugins: [vuetify] }
      }
    );
    expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

It works, the snapshot is ok:

```
// Vitest Snapshot v1, https://vitest.dev/guide/snapshot.html

exports[`Composant ConfirmationModal > Match snapshot 1`] = `
"<v-layout title=\\"test\\" width=\\"100\\" value=\\"true\\">
  <div class=\\"text-center\\">
    <v-dialog width=\\"510\\" class=\\"confirmation-modal\\" persistent=\\"\\" value=\\"false\\">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title class=\\"text-h5 grey lighten-2\\" primary-title=\\"\\"></v-card-title>
        <v-card-text></v-card-text>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn class=\\"btn-ok\\" color=\\"primary\\" text=\\"\\"> OK</v-btn>
          <v-btn id=\\"btn-annulation\\" color=\\"primary\\" text=\\"\\"> Annuler</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</v-layout>"
`;
```

But I have a lot of warnings:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: v-layout
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <Anonymous value=true title="test" width=100  ... > 
  at <VTUROOT>
```

And the same for each Vuetify component I use.

Following the documentation (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/unit-testing/#setup-vitest), I've read that I should use Vuetify in tests this way:

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
})
```

If I do this, no more warnings, but my snapshot becomes useless because almost empty. Here's the full snapshot:

```
exports[`Composant ConfirmationModal > Correspond au snapshot 1`] = `
"<div class=\\"v-layout\\" title=\\"test\\" width=\\"100\\" value=\\"true\\">
  <div class=\\"text-center\\">
    <!---->
    <!---->
  </div>
</div>"
`;
```

Here's my vitest.config.ts if it can help :

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default ({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '');
  return defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    define: {
      'process.env': env
    },
    test: {
      globals: true,
      environment: 'jsdom',
      deps: {
        inline: ['vuetify']
      },
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
      }
    }
  });
};
```

By the way, I don't know if it should be `vite.config.ts` or `vitest.config.ts`. I'm doing this in a component library, so I don't have any Vue app.

Thank you,

Clément

Comment: The rear snapshot is absolutely correct. I mean vue components have to become html you know what I mean

Comment: The second snapshot I gave in my post is not an abstract, it's the full snapshot. I have no problem with components replaced with div. The problem is that it's almost empty. I'm expecting at least <div class="v-dialog"><div class="v-card">...

Answer (score 0):

I've finally figured it out. It comes from the VDialog that has nowhere to attach to.
Just surrounding it with a `<body>` in the template used for mounting in test wasn't enough, I had to stub the VDialog like in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/76018176/3004275